# using IIF in msaccess report

Tags: ms-access, iif-function

I currently have this formula in my report

=(Sum([Final]*[Units]))/Sum([Units]))

Final - Mostly Integer but has the NG mixed in the records 
Units - Integer
Re-Exam - Contains Integer

Now, with my current formula, if [Final] encounters the value NG, the report gives an error, I want to determine the if the value of [Final] is NG, [Re-Exam] will be checked if it contains a value else 0 will be added to the Sum[Final] and if [Re-Exam] contains a value, [Re-Exam]*[Units] will be added to Sum[Final]

the final result displays the result in general number format

I am thinking of using IIF but can't generate the correct formula at the moment and that's what i need to fix

Answer (score 1):

Try using *Val* which returns 0 for a non-numeric string.:

```
=Sum(IIf(Val([Final])=0,Val([Re-Exam]),Val([Final]))*[Units])/Sum([Units])
```

Comment: thanks, but i also need to check the value of [Re-Exam] which can contain a null or numeric value and add this Sum([Re-Exam]*[Units]) to the total sum of Sum([Final]*[Units])